# How to load data in highcharts from text

Tags: highcharts

I would like to use a CSV file as source for a highcharts graph.

Could you give some guidance? I need to understand basically how to get data in the web page.

Do I need to put the function that load the text file in the "series" part of the js function?

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'chart example'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    series: []
};

$.get('test.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        // header line containes categories
        if (lineNo == 0) {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
            });
        }

        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
        // position
        else {
            var series = {
                data: []
            };
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 1) {
                    series.name = item;
                } else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                }
            });

            options.series.push(series);

        }

    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

This is how the data file is structured in the CSV file:

```
Compound,Value
mix1,0.244
mix2,0.453
pureCu,1
pureAg,0.98
```

The value of column 1 is an ID basically, so the distance between each of them could be considered as 1. So technically, the first column would be always from 1 to 15 for example, with the label using the name in the first column

I would like to put the second field on the Y, and on the X the first field; but using the code pasted (which is what is on an example on the Highcharts website), I can't really figure out how to set up correctly the values on each side of the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find tutorials from Highcharts to load data from external file: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing

About refreshing page - yes you can refresh page every n-seconds, however it would be better (I think) to call AJAX to fetch new data from server and then replace it in Highcharts (simply using `chart.series[0].setData( new_array_of_data );`

Comment: Thanks; I saw the entire documentation on the site, but I don't get how you actually bring in data...I know no JS (I use python mostly), so for me is something new and unknown. I know how to write functions but I don't get how highcharts wants them...the example show a $.fuction, and the notation is quite strange. I am trying to get data from 2 columns from a CSV file, in X and Y axis on a simple line chart. Thanks

Comment: `$.function` notation comes from jQuery and it's required to use that way. Another option is to use standalone framework, but that's not the case. Wrap your code inside: `$(function () { .. code comes here .. })` to make sure your code will run after page is loaded.